# Checking if an object exists in an SQL table based on a Column and some object's Field

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am currently trying to check if there exists an instance of an object with a unique ID in a SQL Table. So as to not place duplicates. Here is a sample of what I currently have:

```
string ui = someObj.getUniqueID();

IQueryable<String> checkDataQuery = from cdq in db.SomeObjects
                                           where cdq.UniqueID == ui
                                           select cdq.UniqueID;

if (checkDataQuery != ui) // This is just my attempt at making sure that
                          // the query actually returned something and not 
                          // the string representing nothing found, so if there
                          // is a better checking method that would even more helpful.
```

The main issue I am running into is that I can not access `checkDataQuery` as a `string`. I attempted casting it, and using the `.Single()/.First()` methods, however, the former had no success, and the latter made the single string being returned into a list of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the result with `Enumerable.Any` like:

```
bool ifExists = db.SomeObjects.Any(r=> r.UniqueID == ui);
```

If you want to get the object, then you can use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `null` like:

```
var dbObject = db.SomeObjects.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.UniqueID == ui);
if(dbObject != null)
{
  //record exists
}
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to C# and Linq, if you could, can you explain the "=>" operator, the rest reads fairly straightforward.

Comment: @FenrirProtocol, LINQ uses two styles , [method syntax and query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx). What I have used is method syntax. `=>` used in the code is basically a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)